# Verify MongoDB encryption based on Local Key Management

Tags: mongodb, encryption, mongodb-query

I have configured MongoDB 3.4.16 Enterprise version for native encryption following the [Local Key Management](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/tutorial/configure-encryption/#local-key-management) method as mentioned in the documentation of MongoDB.

I find that, as mentioned in the tutorial I also get the encryption successful message on the command prompt which comes after the operation was successful:

> [initandlisten] Encryption key manager initialized with key file:

My question is, how can I demonstrate the results to other people that with just these configurations the encryption has happened? Like for example, only if I can show the DB data file before and after applying these encryption configurations.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer, rather a comment. Be sure to take note of the notice at the top of the Local Key Management page.

> IMPORTANT
>
> Using the keyfile method does not meet most regulatory key
>   management guidelines and requires users to securely manage their own
>   keys.
>
> The safe management of the keyfile is critical.

Without a dedicated key manager to store and manage keys, it is like leaving the keys to your house under your welcome mat.  Since you are on Enterprise edition, use KMIP and deploy an encryption key manager.  More on encryption key management for MongoDB here: https://info.townsendsecurity.com/mongodb-encryption-key-management-definitive-guide